# Prove: Let $f(x)$ a differentiable function s.t. $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } f'(x) = l' > 0$.So: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } f(x) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

*Question:*
True or False.
Let $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto  \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function s.t. $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } f'(x) = l' > 0$ ($l'$ positive and finite). So: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } f(x) = \infty$

*Answer:*
I answer that this is true and below my proof:

1 - By definition $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } f'(x) = l' > 0$ implies that if we choose $\epsilon = l' / 2 >0$, $\exists x_0$ s.t. $\forall x>x_0$ it will be verify that $f'(x) \in (l'-\epsilon; l'+\epsilon)=(l'/2;3l'/2) \Rightarrow 0<l'/2<f'(x)<3l'/2$. So by the first derivative test $f(x)$ is stricly increasing on the open interval $(x_0, \infty)$.
2 - By absurd let suppose that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } f(x) = l < \infty$.
Let remember that $f(x)$ is differentiable $\forall x$. It means that for all $x$ the following expression is define $f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ . But as $x$ goes to infinity  we will get: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x+h)=l=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)$ for every $h>0$ we can choose.  Hence $f'(x) = 0$ and by assumption it is not possible.
(In a shorter way we could writte: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } f'(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{l-l}{h}=0$)

Q.E.D
Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite. You have to justify why it is allowed to interchange the limits.

Comment: @BrunoKrams Thk for your answer. But as i explained if $x  \rightarrow \infty$ we will get (by absurd assumption)  $f(x+h)=f(x)$ for every $h>0$ . Where i am wrong?

Comment: You only have $\lim f(x+h) = \lim f(x)$ but that does not mean that $f(x +h) = f(x)$. Your conclusion on the derivative however assumes $x$ to be fixed.

Comment: An alternative is to use L Hospital's Rule on $f(x) /x$ to conclude that it tends to $l'$ and then you are done.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh can you be more precise on how to use lhopital rule? (using his contraposition?) Becaus ewe can apply Lhopital rule on $f(x)/x$ only oif we first know that $f(x)$ goes to infinite too.

Comment: @X0-user-0X: L Hospital's Rule applies to two forms "0/0" and "anything/$\infty$". So in second case we don't need to know whether numerator tends to infinity or not. This fact is not sufficiently well known.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh where did you find the form "anything $/\infty$" of the Lhopital theoreù?

Comment: Check the proof given in Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can argue by mean value theorem: Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x) = l'>0$, for any $\epsilon>0$, we have for $y>B_{\epsilon}>0$, $f'(y) > l'-\epsilon$. Let $x$ be such that $x > B_{\epsilon}$ and $f(x)< \infty$. If could not pick such $x$, $f(x) = \infty$, $\forall, x>B_{\epsilon}$ and we are done. By mean value theorem, for every $y>x$, there is a $\psi \in [x,y]$, we have $f(y) - f(x) = f'(\psi) (y-x) > (l'-\epsilon) (y-x)$, for all $y>x>B_{\epsilon}$. Now fix $x$ and increase $y$, we have that $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} f(y)-f(x) >  (l'-\epsilon) \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} (y-x) = \infty$. Hence $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} f(y) = \infty$.

Comment: Thank for your answer. What do you mean by $B_{\epsilon}$

Comment: It is a constant depending only on $\epsilon$.

Comment: +1  YES.  The obvious argument may be to use integrals $f(b) = f(a) + \int_a^b f'(x)\;dx \ge f(a) + (l'-\epsilon)(b-a)$ and let $b \to \infty$.  But we have only assumed $f$ is differentiable, not that $f'$ is integrable.  The way around this is to use the MVT instead of integration.